# Cisco port channel identification through SNMP

Tags: switch, cisco-ios, snmp, port-channel

on a cisco switch is there any way to identify, through SNMP queries, which interfaces are involved and configured in a port channel?

I did some experiment with commons MIB, without result.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance,
Gianluca

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

This page shows some helpful suggestions that might get what you want, assuming you have the same kind of switch and a reasonably similar IOS version in use:

https://community.cisco.com/t5/network-management/snmp-check-etherchannel-interface-members/td-p/1069995

These other questions are similar and have additional information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960157/how-to-map-portchannel-to-interfaces-via-snmp

[how to get port/interface status of cisco switch via snmp](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20827/how-to-get-port-interface-status-of-cisco-switch-via-snmp)

If you put them all together you should be able to get good results for your needs.